# Binary Tree Question - determine the longest path

Tags: tree, binary-tree

Determine the longest set with nodes that are not connected? Is there a similar example online somewhere?

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \   \
  4   5   6
         / \
        7   8

Examples of Sets:
1,4,5,6 = 4
2,6 = 2
1,4,5,7,8 = 5
3,4,5,7,8 = 5

Answer = 5
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "set with nodes that are not connected?" Aren't 1 and 3 linked in the above diagram?

Comment: @templatetypedef apologies, I've corrected it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maximise the set as follows:

Collect every leaf node, and then work upwards in the tree and collect a node when neighter of its children has been collected.

You can implement this with a depth-first, post order, recursive algorithm.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, that creates the example tree and then runs the algorithm on it:

```js
// Standard Node class for a binary tree
class Node {
    constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

// Main algorithm
function getNodes(root) {
    let set = [];
    
    // Recursive function that returns 1 when the
    //    given node has been collected, 0 otherwise.
    function recur(node) {
        if (node != null && recur(node.left) + recur(node.right) == 0) {
            set.push(node.value);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // Traverse the tree in post order fashion
    recur(root);
    
    return set;
}

// Build he example tree
let root = new Node(1,
    new Node(2,
        new Node(4), new Node(5)
    ),
    new Node(3,
        null,
        new Node(6,
            new Node(7), new Node(8)
        )
    )
);

// Run the algorithm
let result = getNodes(root);

// Outout the result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here in the future looking for an answer, here is the easiest method using `Set` in JavaScript

```js
       class Node {
            constructor(value, left=null, right=null) {
                this.x = value;
                this.l = left;
                this.r = right;
            }
        }
        
        // Build the example tree
        let root = new Node(1,
            new Node(2,
                new Node(4), new Node(5)
            ),
            new Node(3,
                null,
                new Node(6,
                    new Node(7), new Node(8)
                )
            )
        );
        
        // Logic starts here
        function findLongestPath(root) {
            if (root === null) return 0
            let hash = new Set();
            return longestPath(root, hash)
        }
        
        function longestPath(node, obj) {
            if (node === null || obj.has(node.x)) { return obj.size }
            obj.add(node.x)
            const leftPath = longestPath(node.l, obj);
            const rightPath = longestPath(node.r, obj);
            obj.delete(node.x)
            return Math.max(leftPath, rightPath);
        }

console.log(findLongestPath(root))
```